# How the "event user count" is calculated for any event in fabric-answer dashboard

Tags: google-fabric

There is a user count ( Event Users) to each event in answer dashboard. How this count is changed as I can see whenever I install the app then only its increased by 1. But I want it to be updated whenever any new user sign in/sign out to my app.
And is there any way to link all events to a particular user or add user info in all events by default so that we don't need to add in each event all the info individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todd from Fabric. Right now it's not possible to track individual users through Answers. You can use custom events and attributes to log these activities, but you will need to set the attributes for each event as they happen. [Check out this page for more info.](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-events.html#event-types)